# Create password protected excel file using Closedxml library

Tags: .net

I am new in c# asp.net and I tried to create XLS file using third party library "Closedxml". Now I also want to protect the XLS file with password how I can achieve this.

Your help would be appreciable.
Thanks in advance
Ashish

Comment: You could just google it and it would give you numerous solutions. Here is one: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7czw9wzs.aspx (Keep in mind that you will need to add the ref to the excel lib in your project) And here is a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/915999/password-protecting-an-excel-file-in-c-sharp

Comment: It looks like you can't password protect it (or remove password protection) with ClosedXML, but @NoelWidmer 's links should be sufficient from protecting it after you've created it with ClosedXML.

Answer (score 7):

Had the same issue - needed to protext an excel file without using the interop libraries.

```
With ClosedXML you can password protect at the worksheet level: 
var ws = wb.Worksheets.Add("someworksheet");
ws.Protect("123");  // 123 will be the password
```

And it looks like you can lock the structure of the workbook (prevent worksheet add/delete/rename) without the option of setting a password, although have not tested this bit extensively:

```
var wb = new XLWorkbook();
wb.Protect(bool LockStrucure, bool LockWindows);
```

references:
[sheet protection example](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Sheet%20Protection)

Comment: this is possible in PowerShell?

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The Excel file opens without requesting a password.

Comment: THIS IS NOT WORKING FOR ME

Answer (score 3):

To protect the file with a password is not possible in ClosedXML, see [github](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/issues/951)

Comment: Downvote because it is possible, see @JesseZ answer.

Comment: check my link, it's not possible, JesseZ answer doesn't work.

Comment: maybe we're talking about different things because JesseZ's answer 100% worked for me. That's for password protecting a worksheet from editing, not the entire file from opening. Is that what you're talking about?

Comment: Yes I'm talking about password protecting the entire file from opening.

Comment: +1 because, @Cerveser, you're absolutely correct. You can protect individual sheets from being edited, but you cannot password protect the document from being opened with ClosedXML. The original question did not specify which type of protection they wanted.