# C# Closed.XML Password Protection

Tags: c#, password-protection, closedxml

I am using c# Closed.XML for creating excel files then i need protect them with a password.

Do you know anyway to protect excel file with a password by Closed.XML, or you know another way to creating password protection?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30341506/create-password-protected-excel-file-using-closedxml-library

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create password protected excel file using Closedxml library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30341506/create-password-protected-excel-file-using-closedxml-library)

Comment: the both i already refer, the string in protect is error