# How to add password to Excel file generated from Report Server using c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, excel, asp.net-mvc

I'm able to download excel through report server.I tried using EpPlus but i was not able to use it with report viewer. I want to add password to the excel file.

```
 public static void SendFileBytes(HttpResponse response, byte[] fileBytes, string fileName, string mimeType)
    {
        if (response != null && fileBytes != null && fileBytes.Length > 0 && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileName) && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(mimeType))
        {
            response.Clear();
            response.Buffer = true;
            response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            response.ContentType = mimeType; // "application/pdf";
            response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(fileName));
            response.Charset = "";
            response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);






            using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(response.OutputStream))
            {

                bw.Write(fileBytes);
                bw.Close();

            }
            response.Flush();
            response.End();
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`

Link reference [Password Protecting an Excel file in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/915999/password-protecting-an-excel-file-in-c-sharp)