# How to set a password to the excel files using ssis C# script

Tags: c#, excel, ssis

Hi I've started working on the SSIS(visual studio 2015) recently. So there is a request from the client, they want me to set a password for the excel file that they are sent me to loading the data into the SQL server.

But for that I need to use the script task to write a code on C# to set the password for each and every excel file.
I've done the lot of reasearch about this C# code but i wasn't able to find the code.
All i got is C# code for the CSV format that's working fine for me & that is entirely different C# format because with that I've tried so many trail & error methods with xlsx Excel format files, so far no luck.
But I need the code for xlsx format excel files or for the zip format also fine for me.

Can anyone please help me.
Give me the straight away code i don't have much time to understand the code itself. My apologies for this comment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Password Protecting an Excel file in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/915999/password-protecting-an-excel-file-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Thanks for suggesting me that existing question. But the microsoft.office.interop.excel is not working in the c# code inside the ssis package.

Comment: Have a look at [*this*](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/protect-the-excel-files-generated-by-ssis-package-part-i)

Comment: Thanks man. I think I need to upgrade my visual studio to do this. In the past also I got this type of c# code that uses the name space called Microsoft.office.interop.excel this isn't working on 2015 visual studio I'll work on this. Thanks dude for the hyperlink.