# Password protect Excel file in C# (protect from opening)

Tags: c#, excel, password-protection

Is it possible to use C# to protect Excel file with a password so that it's not possible to view the file without the password?

I've seen this post: [Password Protecting an Excel file in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/915999/password-protecting-an-excel-file-in-c-sharp)

But it's from 2009, and didn't work for me.

I am using .NET 6.0 if that matters but can use any other if needed

Comment: i think you can use https://www.nuget.org/packages/epplus/ (check the licence) or https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel but i personally never used them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the NuGet package - Free Spire.XLS for .NET to protect Excel file with password.

First, install the required package by using the following command:

```
PM> Install-Package FreeSpire.XLS
```

Next, refer to the following example:

```
using Spire.Xls;

namespace PasswordProtectWorkbook
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Create a Workbook object
            Workbook workbook = new Workbook();

            //Load an Excel file
            workbook.LoadFromFile(@"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\sample.xlsx");

            //Protect workbook with a password
            workbook.Protect("psd-123");

            //Save the workbook to another Excel file
            workbook.SaveToFile("Encrypted.xlsx", ExcelVersion.Version2016);
        }
    }
}
```

This package provides various ways to protect Excel files, you can check this article for more details: [C#/VB.NET: Protect or Unprotect Excel Documents](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Spire.XLS/Spire.XLS-Program-Guide/NET-Protect-Excel-Protect-Excel-Workbook-and-Worksheet.html)

Disclaimer: I work for the company that developed this package.